# [SpringCloudGateway-WebFlux]: Which offset to use for ordering of custom global pre and post filters

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud, project-reactor, spring-cloud-gateway

We have implemented around 10+ custom global ordered pre filter and 3 post filter.

We have set base offset for pre-filter as 5 (motivated from Netflix Zuul FilterConstants.PRE_DECORATION_FILTER_ORDER) and each implemented pre-filter uses its order by incrementing the base offset by 1.

Example: First pre-filter order will be 6, Second pre-filter order will be 7 and so on.

Similarly we have set base offset for post-filter as 1000 and each implemented post-filter uses its order by decrementing the base offset by 1.

There are following 3 post implemented as of now:

1. Manipulated request cookies and header
2. Read response body
3. Invalidates one of the response cookies

However, while implementing post-filter related to read response body figured out that the post-filter must execute after in-built NettyWriteResponseFilter post-filter, whose order is -1. The response will be populated after the execution of NettyWriteResponseFilter filter.

Thus, all the custom post filters operating on response object must execute after NettyWriteResponseFilter, which can be ensured by setting the order of custom post filter less than -1.

As per above observation, could anyone please share any recommendation for the base offset for custom pre and post filters to be implemented?

Any suggestion will be of great help.